# Need help to speed up this code - Python and numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function which processes an input array of dimension (h,w,200) (the number 200 can vary) and returns an array of dimension (h,w,50,3). The function takes ~0.8 seconds for an input array of size 512,512,200.

```
def myfunc(arr, n = 50):
    #shape of arr is (h,w,200)
    #output shape is (h,w,50,3)

    #a1 is an array of length 50, I get them from a different 
    #function, which doesn't take much time. For simplicity, I fix it 
    #as np.arange(0,50)

    a1 = np.arange(0,50)


    output = np.stack((arr[:,:,a1],)*3, axis = -1)

    return output
```

This preprocessing step is done to ~8 arrays in a single batch, due to which loading a batch of data takes 8*0.8 = 6.4 seconds. Is there a way to speed up the computation of myfunc? Can I use libraries like numba for this?

Comment: If your code is working but you just want to optimize it, you should ask the question at Code Review instead: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This function takes 0.8 sec to run? Really? What machine are you using? Are there's other processes running?

Comment: Okay, will do that. I posted it here as I wanted to know if numba can be used to for speed up.

Comment: Your function output an array of shape `(50, 512, 200, 9)` not `(512,512,50,3)`.

Comment: Did you mean something like `arr[..., a1]` by the way?

Comment: I'm using a cluster with a lot of ram and cpu cores. I don't think there is anything else running.

Comment: @Roope the question requires more context about the use case or it will be deemed off-topic at CR

Comment: @QuangHoang There was an error in the output, I changed it so that the output shape is 512, 512, 50, 3.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'm trying to take 50 out of 512 channels and stack the array of shape (h,w,50) in the last dimension to get output of shape (h,w,50,3)

Comment: And you're telling me that takes 0.8 sec? I'm really having a hard time believing that.

Comment: @Roope, performance questions are common here on SO, especially with the [numpy] tag.  CR is better for comprehensive answers about style and organization, and tends to be pickier about completeness.

Comment: @MadPhysicist input array is of dimension (512,512,200). myfunc(input,50) takes 0.8 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I get about the same time:

```
In [14]: arr = np.ones((512,512,200))                                                                        
In [15]: timeit output = np.stack((arr[:,:,np.arange(50)],)*3, axis=-1)                                      
681 ms ± 5.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [16]: np.stack((arr[:,:,np.arange(50)],)*3, axis=-1).shape                                                
Out[16]: (512, 512, 50, 3)
```

Looking at the timings in more detail.

First the index/copy step, takes about 1/3 of the time:

```
In [17]: timeit arr[:,:,np.arange(50)]                                                                       
249 ms ± 306 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

And the `stack`:

```
In [18]: %%timeit temp = arr[:,:,np.arange(50)] 
    ...: output = np.stack([temp,temp,temp], axis=-1) 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                                                     
426 ms ± 367 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

`stack` expands dimensions and then concatenates; so lets call concatenate directly:

```
In [19]: %%timeit temp = arr[:,:,np.arange(50),None] 
    ...: output = np.concatenate([temp,temp,temp], axis=-1) 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                                                     
430 ms ± 8.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

another approach is to use `repeat`:

```
In [20]: %%timeit temp = arr[:,:,np.arange(50),None] 
    ...: output = np.repeat(temp, 3, axis=-1) 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                                                     
531 ms ± 155 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So looks like your code's as good as it gets.

Indexing and concatenate already use compiled code, so I don't expect `numba` to help much (not that I have much experience with it).

Stacking on a new front axis is faster (making (3, 512, 512, 50))

```
In [21]: %%timeit temp = arr[:,:,np.arange(50)] 
    ...: output = np.stack([temp,temp,temp]) 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                                                     
254 ms ± 1.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

That could then be transposed (cheaply), though subsequent operations might be slower (if they require a copy and/or reordering).  A plain `copy` of the full `output` array times at around 350 ms.

---

Inspired by comments, I tried broadcasted assignment:

```
In [101]: %%timeit temp = arr[:,:,np.arange(50)]  
     ...: res = np.empty(temp.shape + (3,), temp.dtype) 
     ...: res[...] = temp[...,None] 
     ...:  
     ...:  
     ...:                                                                                                    
337 ms ± 1.73 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Same ball park.

Another trick is to play with `strides` to make a 'virtual' copy:

```
In [74]: res1 = np.broadcast_to(arr, (3,)+arr.shape)                                                         
In [75]: res1.shape                                                                                          
Out[75]: (3, 512, 512, 200)
In [76]: res1.strides                                                                                        
Out[76]: (0, 819200, 1600, 8)
```

For some reason this does not work with `(512,512,200,3)`.  It may have something to do with the `broadcast_to` implementation.  Maybe someone can experiment with `as_strided`.

Though I can transpose this just fine:

```
np.broadcast_to(arr, (3,)+arr.shape).transpose(1,2,3,0)
```

In any case this is **much** faster:

```
In [82]: timeit res1 = np.broadcast_to(arr, (3,)+arr.shape)                                                  
10.4 µs ± 188 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

(but making a `copy` brings time back up.)

Comment: What about manually preallocating the output and copying to it with slicing?

Comment: Broadcasted copy to a preallocated array takes about the same time as the `stacking`.  In fact any copy of the target size takes about the same time.  `broadcast_to` can make an `as_strided` like pseudo-copy very quickly,

Comment: That won't help OP much since the original question was accessing three separate segments independently.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the detailed analysis. I should probably look into multiprocessing and try to preprocess a batch of 4 images instead of sequential.